# Sort the value with DBNull using Queryable.OrderBy it throws Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

When I try to sort the value with `DBNull` using `Queryable.OrderBy` it throws Exception.

```
    Pet[] pets =
        {
            new Pet {Name = "Barley", Age = 8},
            new Pet {Name = DBNull.Value, Age = 1},
            new Pet {Name = "Boots", Age = 4}
        };

    // Sort the Pet objects in the array by Pet.Name
    IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.AsQueryable().OrderBy(pet => pet.Name);
    foreach (Pet pet in query)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
```

Below code throws exception because I'm using `DBNull`. I know i can overcome this problem by using the code below,

```
   IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.AsQueryable().OrderBy(delegate(Pet pet)
            {
                if (pet.Name is DBNull)
                    return null;
                return pet.Name;
            });
```

But i can't use this code. Is there any way to handle this problem without adding condition check in `OrderBy` function.

Comment: whhy u cant use the below code ?

Comment: Can you share the reason why you don't want to use the above mentioned code.

Comment: which line throws the error? the one BEFORE foreach or the one AFTER foreach?

Comment: @sivakumar, did we helped you? did you solved the problem?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Yes, I have used the below code. So Querable.OrderBy won't work with DBNull by default. we have to workaround. IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.AsQueryable().OrderBy(delegate(Pet pet)
            {
                if (pet.Name is DBNull)
                    return null;
                return pet.Name;
            });

Answer (score 2):

DBNull is part of older Data technology. Linq & EF no longer need DBNull. Just use null instead.

```
Pet[] pets =
    {
        new Pet {Name = "Barley", Age = 8},
        //Using null is fine
        new Pet {Name = null, Age = 1}, 
        new Pet {Name = "Boots", Age = 4}
    };

// Sort the Pet objects in the array by Pet.Name
IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.AsQueryable().OrderBy(pet => pet.Name);
foreach (Pet pet in query)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have ran the code and got an exception:

```
At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

that is because i don't know what type is Name is. i'm guessing whatever it is, it doesn't implement `IComparable`. Your `CustomClass`(the class on `Name`) should either implement the `IComparable<T>` interface or you should pass in an `IComparer` on your `OrderBy()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code. As Querable.OrderBy won't work with DBNull by default. we have to use workaround. IEnumerable query = pets.AsQueryable().OrderBy(delegate(Pet pet) { if (pet.Name is DBNull) return null; return pet.Name; });